# Swagger UI causes failure in Multipart-FormData request from spring-resources with file and json-object

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger, multipartform-data

I'm using spring-boot in the version 1.4.3 in my project. The Project provides some REST-endpoints and uses springfox-swagger 2.6.1 to generate the api-documentation.
This works just fine for almost all of my requests and I can successfully try the endpoints.

However, this stops working on a multipart-formdata request, containing a MultipartFile and an json-object. The problem is similar to the following issue:

[JHipster, spring rest service with MultiPart and JSON, swagger/curl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790560/jhipster-spring-rest-service-with-multipart-and-json-swagger-curl-error)

I got it working in this manner, but for me, it's not a valid solution to change the json-object to a request parameter due to it's possible size (during a try with a bigger json-object I got an error telling, that the header is too big).

Here are the sample code, and error message:

Endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE },
  consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createApproval(@RequestPart(required = true) @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file,
  @RequestPart(required = true) MyClass json, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

This generates a swagger API as follows:

```
parameter - value              - description - parameter type - data type
file      - (upload file)      - file        - formData       - file
json      - string-value-filed - json        - formData       - undefined
```

Executing this with valid data generates the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've also written a test for it, this works just nice:

```
final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder saveRequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(baseUrl).file(mockFile)
    .file(jsonFile).contentType(contentType);
saveRequestBuilder.with(new RequestPostProcessor() {
  @Override
  public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setMethod("PUT");
    return request;
  }
});
mockMvc.perform(saveRequestBuilder).andExpect(status().isCreated()).andDo( and so on...
```

I Also tried some changes with @ApiImplicitParam. Most of them didn't change anything. using the following change, I got a different API, but an error then tells me that's the json-object is not present.

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "json", value = "the json object", required = true,
  dataType = "MyClass", paramType = "body")
```

So, does anyone know how to get this to work during the swagger-ui-doc?

Thanks for your help beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just found a solution. As it seems, I already linked it in my question.

I switched the json-parameter to a simple string and converted it manually to my class works just fine. So the solution in the linked Question works fine here, too.

So a short Lessons learned:

Spring-Swagger-Combination has some problems in multipart request to convert json-input to an object. A workaround is using a simple string and convert it by yourself. I hope they will make it work in the future.

Additionally to the linked solution: It doesn't has to be a RequestParam, RequestPart works fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/fileupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile uploadfile) {

Try to match your controller with the above. Most probably its something to with @RequestPart annotation.